# USB no longer stays connected

Tags: 2.2-froyo, usb

I have a Samsung Intercept running 2.2.1. I've been using USB debugging for several months, and recently (no recent changes to the phone) the connectivity just dies after a few seconds, not long enough to load new apks. The same goes for Mass Storage: it dies as soon as I try to transfer files to my computer.

I have a handful of other phones, and using the same setup and cable I'm able to connect via USB to them, so I know it isn't my computer or cable.

Before I try to replace my phone, as I need it for testing, does anyone know of a software reason for this to be happening, or is it pretty much assuredly the usb pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you one suggestion. Based on the what you have posted and based on what I understand do the following thing.

*. Backup all your data through Bluetooth and do a Settings Reset.

`(Settings --> Privacy --> Settings reset)`.

And try to connect to Computer using your USB setup. If still no help do the next step

*. Do a Factory Reset.
`(Settings --> Privacy --> Factory data reset).`

If still no help then that might be Hardware issue. Go to any Samsung Customer service center. They might replace only the Pins section.

Comment: Okay. I tried both the resets, and that didn't fix things, but I'll take it to Samsung and see if I can get the usb pins replaced. Thanks!

Comment: This ended up being the only solution. Sprint is letting me trade my phone back in.